# get alerted when a file is downloaded

Tags: 2010, document-library, alert

I have a document library in sharepoint 2010 and our product management team want to be alerted when  a file downloaded by a user. is there any way to achieve this? 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a download event in SharePoint. But there is an audit reporting facility which will show you every document that has been accessed, by whom and when.

Comment: is it something which can be implemented?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397403%28office.12%29.aspx